# specific term for words that imitate sounds

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I often in children's literature come across the rrrrrrrrrrrrS when a plane take off and the bumpity-bump when someone falls, etc.

and I am wondering if these are called with a specific term?
written sounds? transcribed sounds maybe?

Comment: "bumpity-bump" requires a hyphen.

Comment: We in the U.S. assume the onomatopoeic words we're familiar with--animal sounds for example--actually represent the way animals sound.  To the people in another culture, on the other hand, the word "moo" may sound (when translated and pronounced)completely different. The same may be true for meow, baaaa, ribbit, bzzzzz, neigh, ad infinitum.  Kind of makes me wonder if there is a toy manufacturer in the U.S. that makes those animal-sound toys that kids in the U.S. play with that modifies them to be culturally sensitive to the kids in the various countries to which the company exports them!

Comment: It's the other way around. The toys are mostly made in China, for export to America, so the moos and oinks probably sound funny to the people who manufacture them.  I wonder whether the Cinese factory workers have any clue about the Western holidays (Easter , Xmas, Halloween) for which they make all the decorations, costumes, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a descriptive word out of the sound that something makes is called [onomatopoeia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia):

> Definition of ONOMATOPOEIA 
>   1 : the naming of a thing or action by a
>   vocal imitation of the sound associated with it (as buzz, hiss) 
>   2 : the use of words whose sound suggests the sense

The term is derived from the Greek words *ὄνομα* (*onoma*, name) and *ποιεῖν* (*poiein*, to make, to create). The same root as *poet*.

Comment: Well I guess bumpity bump falls under that category but what about rrrrrrrrrrr? I mean it's not lexicalized.

Comment: I'd say it still applies @rery. See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) page on _onomatopoeia_, their example is "tic-tac" for the sound a clock makes, that seems equivalent.

Comment: That's the first time I've hear *tic-tac* for the sound of a clock. AFAIK, in BrE it's always referred to as *tick-tock* - at least it was when I was a child.

Comment: I can't speak to English, but in Dutch, we use onomatopoeia for both a word that is etymologically related to a sound ("buzzing"), and an actual literary attempt at a sound effect ("ZZZOOOOMMMMM! He raced past us."). I can only assume the same applies across languages.

Comment: @Flater that's precisely what the definition I cited states. _Zoooommmm!_ is a word the moment you utter it, and so falls into the second sense.

Comment: *(Again, this is biased towards how I was taught grammar in (Belgian Dutch) school, but...)* isn't there a major difference between a word (as a grammatical part of a sentence) and an actual existing word (i.e. properly defined and accepted as part of the language)? Zooommmmm would fall under the former category but not the latter. Again, as I was taught.

Comment: @Flater not for me, no. A word is anything used as such. "I flangered the flizzes floutlessly" is a sentence with 5 words, despite only two of them existing in any dictionary. For example, I could make a word of your name and say "He was _flatered_". How could you describe that if not as a _word_? Actually, [linguists don't even use](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123851/are-homonyms-considered-single-words#comment255022_123851) the term _word_ since its definition is so fuzzy. Also consider how many words is _bow_? Would you count each of its meanings separately?

Comment: You're right in saying "He was flatered" is a sentence with three words. But I'd be just as right in responding "Flatered? That's not a word!". Either imply their own definition ("part of sentence" as opposed to "has been defined"). It depends on whether you're interpreting its use in a grammatical structure, or are focusing on its meaning.

Comment: @Flater precisely. That's why _word_ is not the right word here.

Comment: I'm just glad that onomatopoeia is spelt like it sounds.