# Are homonyms considered single words?

Tags: homophones, homonyms

There are many homonyms in the English language, words that are spelled the same and pronounced the same but have different meanings. A few examples:

- A grizzly *bear* can *bear* great weight.
- I *stake* out the house while perched on a *stake*.
- I took a *bow* after shooting my *bow*.
- Take your *pick* of any *pick* or shovel.
- I came to *see* the Bishop's *see*.

Are these considered one word or two? Does it perhaps depend on their etymology? Maybe if both meanings can be traced to the same root they are one word and if they derive from different sources they are two? Alternatively, how are words defined? Is it in terms of spelling, of meaning, of origin or a combination of the three? The free dictionary [defines](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word) *word* as

> A sound or a combination of sounds, or its representation in writing or printing, that symbolizes and communicates a meaning and may consist of a single morpheme or of a combination of morphemes.

That definition can be read as describing homonyms being both single (a word is a representation of sound in writing) and multiple (a word communicates a meaning) words.

Comment: These questions are answered in answers at 'Q: Is there a term for the phenomenon where the same word forms more than one part of speech?' ( http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=+phenomenon+where+the+same+word+forms+more+than+one+part+of+speech%3F )

Comment: I wouldn't dare venture a guess as to your first questions.  As to your last question, the "identical words" are called that because they share a commonality or a common identity in some way:  some because of sound; some because of spelling; and some because of meaning.  At least at first blush, that's what they seem to be.  I'll take my "extra points" in the form of cash, please.  My address is:  Rhetorician, 666 Venal Lane, New Mammon, New Mexico 66666 USA.  Thanks!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, your answer there is almost exactly what I am looking for. You seem to be implying that words are defined in terms of meaning alone, in which case homonyms are multiple words, is that correct? Also, if I understand you correctly, multiple entries in a dictionary means multiple words. Is that true? I had always thought that dictionary entries were simply divided according to meaning but still described the same word if the same spelling were used. I guess I am looking for the formal linguistics definition of _word_.

Comment: @rhetorician that can't be it since each of the groups you mention has its own place in the diagram (homophones, homonyms and synonyms) and "identical words" are separate. I think I'll post a question for this alone though (and I will be mailing you a check shortly).

Comment: @rhetorician brownie points removed and associated to a [new question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/123853/25030).

Comment: There's also the homophone _bare_, which is either a stative adjective or its causative verb, and is indistinguishable from _bear_ in language. How many words are there, anyway? Good question. Try counting the words in [this puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/HowManyWords.pdf) (from a freshman class; the phone number's no good anymore), and then check out the [three different ways we mean "word"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf), exemplified with _lie_ and its ilk.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks for the links, I wish I could have attended one of your classes (though I think that you're being sneaky with the contractions). The verb vs noun or adjective issue is another that I find interesting. Would you consider _bear_ (v) and _bear_ (a) as different words? I assume they have a similar history to the recent verbification of _impact_.

Comment: No, _bear_ the animal and _bear_ the verb come from completely different sources, as different as _bare_. I don't have to consider whether they're "different words" or not, because the concept is so ill-defined that it's unanswerable. They're all scrambled together in your brain, arranged in whatever way you've arranged them over your English-speaking life, and the same is true for everybody else. How do you propose to count **that**?

Comment: @JohnLawler ouch, sorry, I mean _bare_ (v) and _bear_ (a). Still, for you at least, words are defined in terms of their origin? Homonyms of different descent are separate words while those that share their origin can be considered as the same word?

Comment: @terdon:  "Identical" is analogous to familial resemblances among biological siblings.  Sometimes the commonality might be a certain look ("spelling"--either the same or different); a certain sound of voice or manner of speaking ("pronunciation/sound"--either the same or different); or a certain sex ("meaning"--either the same or different).  The identical parts can be traced to common genetic material from mom and dad (regarding, e.g., eye-, hair-, and skin color), but it might be expressed differently (e.g., female with blue eyes; male with brown eyes, etc.).  Unity within diversity.

Comment: @terdon: No. Words are not defined in terms of their origin for me. For me "words" are not defined at all. I'm a professional linguist and if I'm trying to be precise (as one should in definitions), I wouldn't use the term "word" at all. I'd talk about lexical items, semantics, etymologies, pronunciations, phonosemantics, and probly a few other terms. What I'm trying to say is that "How many words?" questions, or "Are X and Y considered single words?" questions are the wrong question. There's nothing to count. "Word" is a popular term, and does not represent real language.

Comment: @JohnLawler ah, OK, now I get it. Do you think you could whip that into answer form? Perhaps explaining what "lexical items" are to a linguist (I take it that is what is used in the field for most cases where a layman would use _word_)?

Comment: By the way, in your 4th example, _sow_ is pronounced in different ways (rhyming with _cow_ and _low_ respectively), at least in BrE.

Comment: @DavidR good point, I used another example, thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawler For once I will play devil's advocate (I trust you'll forgive me; I think you know how much I respect your expertise). Isn't it disingenuous to use words to state, if not in so many words, that there are no words? Isn't the admirable precision of your preferred terminology an effort to make sense of _words_? Could linguistics even exist if words did not? Words must be _something_, after all. Wouldn't at least one goal of linguistics be to answer the very question you here claim has no answer? Isn't answering "what is a word?" analogous to finding the Holy Grail?

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg - We can wait for John Lawler to answer, but I don't think he means "there are no words." Instead, he's pointing out the term "word" is so nebulous that talking in terms of "words" leads to confusion all too often. Take the question, "Is a phrasal verb one word or two?" The answer could be either: one could argue that it's one word made up of two words – which sounds rather paradoxical. I think Mr. Lawler is saying that it's best to just not go there, and use more precise descriptors instead.

Comment: @J.R. And of course, I'm being mischievous is overinterpreting his comments as if he _were_ saying there is no such thing, but I have a sneaky point. I'm saying there is value in coming up with a meaningful and precise use of the term "word," rather than simply say it's intrinsically too imprecise, and run off to hide behind other terms that are created for the specific purpose of having more precision. I _like_ the word "word." I don't want to relegate it to some sort of impaired, patronized status.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg - Upon my word, I'll take your word for it. ;^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries have long had to contend with this issue. The word *[run](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run)*, for example, has 50 or so meanings as a verb, and another 30 or so as a noun, but they all are grouped under one single dictionary entry. On the other hand, *bow* has three separate entries.

Most print dictionaries denote this using superscripted numerals for each separate entry, much like NOAD does (see screen shot below). In contrast, the online dictionary by Collins uses a numeral in a blue square for each entry to denote the same thing, as can be seen at [their listing for *bow*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bow)).

As for your last example:

> I came to see the Bishop's see.

I'd say that *see* and *see* are not the "same word," based on how they are [listed in the dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see).

However, as John Lawler has mentioned in his comments, it depends on who is counting, and what the count represents. In the sentence:

> He had had a cold.

*had* and *had* are two separate words (it **is** a five-word sentence, after all), yet those two *hads* happen to map to the same *dictionary entry*, whereas, in the earlier sentence, *see* and *see* map to two different dictionary entries.

So it all depends on what your definition of *word* is.

[image]
<sup>**NOTE**: Some definitions have been removed from this image in the interest of conserving space</sup>

Comment: So, for you, _bow_ would be three words?

Comment: @terdon: If you asked me how many repeated words were in the sentence _She put a red bow on the bow of the ship,_ I would say there is one repeated word: the word _the_. If you asked me how many repeated words were in the sentence _She tied the red bow to the quiver and bow,_ I would answer that there were two repeated words: _bow_ and _the_. The words _bow_ and _bow_ are the "same words" in the first sentence, but different words in the second sentence – that's how the dictionary lists them.

Answer (score -2):

A word is a sound (in speech) or a letter-group (in writing) that has a particular meaning.  So "bear" and "bear" and even "bare" are distinct words.  Even words that mean the same thing (like "automobile" and "motor car") are different words (obviously).

One of the most striking examples of a homophone is the pair "entrance" and "entrance" (accent on the first syllable, or on the second).

Comment: I think your two "entrances" are not homophones, but homographs and further are heteronyms. (see @terdon's excellent venn diagram find: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123853/what-are-identical-words-as-distinct-from-homonyms